# HTML - CSS: Styling <object>?

Tags: html, css, object

If my div container has this:

```
<div id="container"><img src...
```

I can style the image by this:

```
CSS
#container img{ ... }
```

For object tag

```
<div id="container"><object ...
```

How do I address it? I tried this:

```
CSS
#container object{ width: 100px; }
```

But it does not work.

Assume the I cant define "id" or "class" for the object tag

I am using tinymce to embed to youtube video. And the code will be rendered like this:

```
<div id="container">
...

    <div id="content">
      <p>
      <object width="435" height="350" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/l9caxMr9RgY">
      <param value="http://www.youtube.com/v/XXXXXX" name="src"></object>
      </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope... I embed youtube video to my page using tinymce. I cant assign id or class, and having problem styling it

Comment: You can wrap entire object into another div tag.. or if you want to style youtube player you have to use player theme..

Comment: @KillerFish: Could you please post as answer, and give me very simple sample code. So that, if it works, I could pick your answer as best answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already add size and width to the object `style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"`

[Example](http://www.jsfiddle.net/c9ch5/2/)

Comment: Sorry, that was my testing code, just to make sure it can be styled. I have remove it. The original code is without the style attribute

Comment: Problems solved by your example link. The new problem is that: when I set the height, it must be in pixels, I cant set it in %. Never mind, I will google it

Answer (score 3):

An object tag *can* be styled using CSS.  Ref [link text](http://www.java2s.com/Code/HTMLCSSReference/HTML-Tag-Reference/objectCSSAttributesandJavaScriptStyleProperties.htm)

The reason width didn't work in your example is that its a HTML attribute only and not accessible with CSS (see list in link above).

I would recommend that you put the object into a wrapper div (give the object a width of 100%) and control the width of the wrapper div with css.

Comment: Err...  So, if I cant wrap the object (as I mentioned in the question, the code was rendered by tinymce), then I cant style it?

Comment: If its wrapped in a p (because of tinymce), then you can style it in your stylesheet using adjacent selector eg #container #content p + object { ..styles here ..}

Answer (score 1):

You can assign an id or class for the object tat, that is perfectly correct. If you want the object to adapt to the width of its parent, just set its width to 100%. If you are using the `<object>` to embed flash, set the width for the `<embed>` tag also.

Comment: I cant assign id or class. Is there any way to call it? I will post more code, give me a minute

Answer (score 0):

To include text, this worked for me in Firefox 43.0. There are 3 files:

test.html:

```
<html><head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" media="all" />
</head><body>
<h3>Test</h3>
<object type="text/html" data="include.html"></object>
</body></html>
```

test.css:

```
object {width:24em;margin-top:-1em;}
.included {background-color:#ffe;font-size:12px;font-family:'Droid Serif';}
```

include.html - to format text inside the object, tags (like these) seem to be necessary:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" media="all" />
<div class="included">
Your included text here...
</div>
```