# Style <object> content from container page

Tags: html, css, styling, html-object

I have a main page, that will load dependant html through  so something like that :

```
<html>
    <head>
      <style>object span {background-color: coral !important;}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
       ...regular page...
       <object type="text/html" data="external-uri.html">
    </body>
</html>
```

I would like that the main page will be able to enforce style over the dependant object loaded.
In the fictional example i would like to set  background color.Is there a way to achieve that or  are somewhat isolated?

Comment: Not in this form. What you could do is load the external element using a server side query such as a cURL request and then use some Javascript or similar server side coding to manipulate the DOM elements in the received data before then outputting this result to your own HTML . However, there are numerous pitfalls to this.

Comment: @Martin i have considered to use jQuery load method. But embed a full HTML directly in a div does not sound a good option to me. What others optiond did you think i have to fetch an extenral HTML resource, embed it in the page but try to normalize the style (eg font family) ?

Comment: Possibly you can add an id element to your `<object>` and then apply CSS style sheets to elements within that `#styleTag` ?

Comment: @Martin sure, i can manipulate the host page as i prefer. but my goal is that i would like to style the content of the object (after the external resource is loaded). The problem here is that customer create html fragment that the host page laod through the <object>, but sometimes there are styles in the fragment that need to be striped. So basically i would like to find a way to apply styling from host page to the laoded fragment (on which i have no control)

Comment: you misunderstand. I mean once the child is loaded inside the object you can use CSS referencing to edit the child data; such as `#objectid body { background-color: coral; }` .

Comment: @Martin yes yes I have understood that, and tomorrow it will be the first thing I would try. The host page to me is the page that contains <object> tag and where I would like to put CSS to normalize content loaded inside <object>. I have only repeated what is my issue from the beginning to be sure (sorry probably this plus my broken English was source of confusion). This because even without Id, this was one of my first attempt (does not work), and would like to be sure to have well understood. Now that it's clear to me I'll test that with id, thanks again

Comment: @Martin i have added css to the main page, that use <object> id to target it, and try to set to coral the background color (with important). But the html loaded inside the <object> seems to not care about that. I have made my test with latest chorme version 112.0.56.xx.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253362/discussion-between-skary-and-martin).

Comment: HTML: `<object id='myID'>` and CSS: `#myID body { background-color:#000 !important; }` for example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML - CSS: Styling <object>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437614/html-css-styling-object)